# Remove query string in url when user reloads page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have am logging in users and redirecting them to `http://domain.com/profile/#welcomemessage` or `http://domain.com/profile/?msg=showwelcomemessage`

So basically it shows welcome message based on query string.When Users reload the page I want  to remove the query.i.e..basically I want to show the welcome message only once.

If this is not possible.Should I use `localstorage` ? will this work on all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for

```
window.history.replaceState
```

Usage:

```
window.history.replaceState( {} , 'foo', '/foo' );
```

From [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-history-interface):

> history  . replaceState(data, title [, url  ] )
>
> Updates the current entry in the session history to have the given
>   data, title, and, if provided and not null, URL.

or you can use localStorage like this:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem("visited")) {
    //yourmessage

    localStorage.setItem("visited", "true");
}

//clear the localStorage when the tab is closed
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.removeItem("visited");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` sounds like the way to go. Or a session if you are more server-orientated. `localStorage` does work in [ie8 and above](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#Browser_compatibility)

For `localStorage`:

```
if (!localStorage.hideWelcomeMessage) {
   document.getElementById('welcome-message').style.display="block";
   localStorage.hideWelcomeMessage = true;
}
```

and html:

```
<div id="welcome-message" style="display:none;">Welcome!</div>
```

The above assumes the id is "welcome-message" but of course you can change that up.